# How to patch a Windows 7 machine to fix recent Security Essentials exploit?

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-update, ms-security-essentials

I have a Windows 7 machine, and I have it set to only manually allow updates from Windows update

There is this exploit that needs to be patched.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/4022344.aspx

I'm looking at my Windows Security Essentials version on Windows 7, and it's v1.1.13701.0, meaning it's still vulnerable.  I want it to be up to v 1.1.13704.0, which is not vulnerable to that exploit.

I downloaded and installed the Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - May 2017 (KB890830) update, and restarted my machine.  I figured that was the update.

After rebooting, I'm still on v1.1.13701.0.  The update I just mentioned is listed as installed.

There is no information that I can find online.  The microsoft documents online are utterly worthless, not telling me how to actually manually do an update myself:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2510781/microsoft-malware-protection-engine-deployment-information

Does anybody know what specific actual update I have to apply to patch my Windows Security Essentials on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Per another person's post answer:

[Security Update for Microsoft Malware Protection Engine (Advisory 4022344)](https://superuser.com/questions/1207519/security-update-for-microsoft-malware-protection-engine-advisory-4022344)

I had to also manually update Security Essentials using the "Update" button in the SE interface.

Answer (score -1):

The update that fixes the problem was not released over windows update, but over the signature updates in security essentials.